# How to use Promise.all + Array.prototype.map() to fetch different data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have an array of IDs and I'm trying to fetch data with each of it and return it all as a component state.

```
let urls = commentsIds.map(id => `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json?print=pretty`);

useEffect(() => {
  fetchComments();
}, [])

const fetchComments = async () => {
  let fetchedComments = [];
  Promise.all(
    urls.map(async (url) => {
      let response = await fetch(url)
      let data = await response.json();
      fetchedComments.push(data);
      console.log(fetchedComments)
    })
  )
  setComments(fetchedComments);
}
```

It works fine when I fetch only one ID:

```
const fetchComments = async () => {
  let fetchedComments = [];
  const response = await fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/25322480.json?print=pretty`);
  const data = await response.json();
  fetchedComments.push(data)
  console.log(fetchedComments)
}
```

But not in the first case with Promise.all. Sometimes Promise.all does console.log when I change code and do not reload the page, but it's still not rendered on page:

```
<div>
  {comments.map(comment => (
    <p key={comment}>{comment.text}</p>
  ))}
</div>
```

In the second case with just one ID both console.log and rendering work perfectly so I probably messed up Promise.all but I can't find where and how exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the fix:

```
const fetchComments = async () => {
    const response = await Promise.all(
      urls.map((url) => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()))
    )
    const fetchedComments = [].concat.apply([], response);
    setComments(fetchedComments);
  }
```